# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set_mode'

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

Trying to code game but get this error.

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set_mode'

```
from pygame import *
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from random import randint, choice
from IPython.core.display import display

SCREEN = display.set_mode((800, 600))
FONT = FONT_PATH + 'space_invaders.ttf'
IMG_NAMES = ['ship', 'mystery',
             'enemy1_1', 'enemy1_2',
             'enemy2_1', 'enemy2_2',
             'enemy3_1', 'enemy3_2',
             'explosionblue', 'explosiongreen', 'explosionpurple',
             'laser', 'enemylaser']
IMAGES = {name: image.load(IMAGE_PATH + '{}.png'.format(name)).convert_alpha()
          for name in IMG_NAMES}
```

Also,

NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: you haven't initialize image variable and directly calling function  . you need to initialize image variable

Answer (score 1):

You do `from pygame import *` but that will not allow you to call e.g. `display.set_mode`/`image.load` since `display` and `image` modules, too.

Your code should look like this:

```
import pygame
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from random import randint, choice

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
FONT = FONT_PATH + 'space_invaders.ttf'
IMG_NAMES = ['ship', 'mystery',
             'enemy1_1', 'enemy1_2',
             'enemy2_1', 'enemy2_2',
             'enemy3_1', 'enemy3_2',
             'explosionblue', 'explosiongreen', 'explosionpurple',
             'laser', 'enemylaser']
IMAGES = {name: pygame.image.load(IMAGE_PATH + '{}.png'.format(name)).convert_alpha()
          for name in IMG_NAMES}
```

Generally, you should avoid global imports like `from pygame import *`.

(I guess `from IPython.core.display import display` was an auto import from your IDE or something like this).